# How to maintain a common datetime format as per locale of user using the web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime-format

I've the datetime stored in **UTC format** in my database. I want to have a common API that should convert the datetimes format(`mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`) according to the browser `culture/locale` of the user using the application.

Currently I'm using

```
 string temp = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yy", ,DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

Also, in javascript how can I take care for the same.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks